# Set onlyIf dependency on Gradle plugin task

Tags: java, gradle, build, closures, gradle-plugin

I've implemented a Gradle plugin in Java. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2015/03/22/a-gradle-plugin-written-in-java).

My plugin class looks as follows:

```
public class DemoPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getExtensions().create("DemoSetting", DemoPluginExtension.class);

        project.getTasks().create("demo", DemoTask.class);
    }
}
```

Currently I am intended to implement the onlyIf feature but unfortunately I did not succeed yet.

My try is the following:

```
public class DemoPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        DemoPluginExtension ext = project.getExtensions().create("demoSetting", DemoPluginExtension.class);

        Closure closure = new Closure(this) {
            public Object doCall() {
                return ext.isExecuteTask();
            }
        };

        project.getTasks().create("demoProperties", demoTask.class).onlyIf(closure);
    }
}
```

The error I am observing is the following:

> What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':demo'.
>   Cannot call Task.setOnlyIf(Closure) on task ':demo' after task has started execution.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint for solving the issue.

Comment: Could you please provide a full, compilable example?

Comment: Closures are a Groovy concept. Even if Java provides support for handling closures, I would suggest to use the Java equivalents in the Gradle API, in this case the `onlyIf(Spec<? extends Task>)` method.

Comment: Finally, I've solved it by implementing the method public Object call(Object arguments) instead of public Object doCall().

Comment: @Opal: unfortunately I could not provide a fully compilable example due to the fact that it is inside a big productive project that is quite difficult (and time consuming) to extract. Sorry!

Comment: @pafede2 Please add an answer to your own question, if you solved your problem on your own. You can even mark your answer as accepted. This way, another user with the same problem may find your solution and the question won't stay unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it using the following code:

```
public class DemoPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        DemoPluginExtension ext = project.getExtensions().create("demoSetting", DemoPluginExtension.class);

        project.getTasks().create("demoProperties", demoTask.class).onlyIf(new Closure(this) {
            public Object call(Object arguments) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please note the implementation of the method

> public Object call(Object arguments)

instead of

> public Object doCall()